# importing complex numbers from excel to array in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, complex-numbers

I am able to import the column, but when I print the array the values are formatted like that:

```
[['value1'] 
 ['value2']
```

and so on...

I don't want the '    '.

I am trying to import a column composed by complex numbers from excel to python I'd like to have an array as an object in python.

```
import numpy as np  
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("Dati.xls", sheet_name="Ysh_pu")
Ysh = df.as_matrix()
```

At the moment I obtain the following output:

```
[['0,00000000000000 + 0,00117108525682811i']
 ['0,00000000000000 + 0,00155994104529390i']
 ['0,00000000000000 + 0,00127766055260943i']
 ['0,00000000000000 + 0,00101368008176161i']
 ['0,00000000000000 + 0,00152052018977579i']]
```

but I'd like an output as follows:

```
[[0,00000000000000 + 0,00117108525682811i]
 [0,00000000000000 + 0,00155994104529390i]
 [0,00000000000000 + 0,00127766055260943i]
 [0,00000000000000 + 0,00101368008176161i]
 [0,00000000000000 + 0,00152052018977579i]
```

Comment: What do you wish to do with your output? If it's just for human legibility you can do some string manipulation on it before printing it out. If you're trying to produce a Python data structure, I'm not sure why you're so concerned about how it gets rendered for display. As it stands, your desired output is not valid Python syntax, since numeric literals use `.` instead of `,` as the decimal separator, `cmath` complex literals use `j` instead of `i`, and the latter would simplify to just the imaginary part without showing the `0 +`, with or without the extra decimals.

Comment: I need to import this vector to do a series of operations with other matrix and arrays. The '' doesn't give the opportunity to do so. That's why I'd like not to have them.

Answer (score 0):

In python, use j instead of i for complex numbers. Then in your data, replace comma (,) with dot (.)

OLD:

```
0,00000000000001 + 0,00117108525682811i
```

NEW:

```
0.00000000000001 + 0.00117108525682811j
```

**DEMO:**

```
c = 0.00000000000001 + 0.00117108525682811j
print(type(c))
print(c)
```

Result:

```
<class 'complex'>
(1e-14+0.00117108525682811j)
```

Comment: I've made the changes you suggest, but I still have in the output the ''.